# Using Ant for S3 Uploading

Tags: ant, amazon-s3

I tried to implement the [awstasks Class](http://code.google.com/p/awstasks/) for uploading files via an ant script to an S3 bucket.

Downloaded all dependencies and used the following code:

```
<taskdef name="S3Upload" classname="dak.ant.taskdefs.S3Upload">
<classpath refid="classpath.compile"/>
</taskdef>

    <target name="final2S3">
        <basename property="customer.id" file="${basedir}"/>
        <basename property="customer.name" file="${basedir.parent.parent}"/>
        <basename property="customer.campaign" file="${basedir.parent}"/>
        <basename property="customer.final" file="${basedir.parent}\_final\${customer.id}\"/>

        <S3Upload verbose="true"
                        accessId="${aws.accessId}"
                        secretKey="${aws.secretKey}"
                        bucket="${aws.bucket}\${customer.id}"
                        publicRead="true">

                <fileset dir="${customer.final}">
                    <include name="**/*.json"/>
                    <include name="**/*.swf"/>
                </fileset>
        </S3Upload>
    </target>
```

I get the following error:

> `Reference classpath.compile not found.`

I tried to set the property classpath.compile to the lib folder in the Ant home but nothing changes.

Comment: found a solution by follwing the tutorial below: 
http://edvanbeinum.com/use-ant-to-deploy-your-static-website-to-amazon-s3